# How to detect pending changes in libgit2sharp?

Tags: c#, .net, libgit2sharp

In libgit2sharp https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/ how do you check for pending/uncommitted changes?

Comment: You can also have a look on the  `RepositoryStatus status = repo.Index.RetrieveStatus();` method further info in the [unit tests](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/StatusFixture.cs)

Comment: @nemesv this should really be an answer ... it's really good :)

Comment: It looks like repo.Index.RetrieveStatus() is deprecated in favor of repo.RetrieveStatus()

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
///DEPRECATED - see comment from @derptastic
public bool HasUncommittedChanges
{
    get
    {
        using (var repo = new Repository(repositoryRoot))
        {
            RepositoryStatus status = repo.RetrieveStatus();
            return status.IsDirty;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to @Derptastic for the link to [LibGit2Sharp Wiki](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/git-diff)

Comment: This has given me false positives on repos where git itself doesn't find uncommitted changes, but `repo.isDirty` returns true. If you want a simple bool check for git diff (or essentially, "Do I have uncommitted changes"), from the official docs - https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/git-diff - `repo.Diff.Compare<TreeChanges>().Count > 0`

Answer (score 7):

The following lines of code will provide the filename and the state of that file.

```
foreach (var item in repo1.RetrieveStatus())
{
  Console.WriteLine(item.FilePath);
  Console.WriteLine(item.State);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `repository.Diff.Compare()`.

```
    /// <summary>
    ///   Show changes between the working directory and the index.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name = "paths">The list of paths (either files or directories) that should be compared.</param>
    /// <returns>A <see cref = "TreeChanges"/> containing the changes between the working directory and the index.</returns>
    public virtual TreeChanges Compare(IEnumerable<string> paths = null)
```

Passing no paths at all should give all changes.